# How do i measure -50 v to 50 v using At-mega micro-controller

Tags: voltage, adc, measurement

I am working on a project where i require to measure -50 v to 50 v using At-mega micro controller(10 Bit ADC). I have tried voltage divider circuit for the positive side of the voltage range which works fine. ADC doesn't measure input voltage below 0 volts. i have done some research online and lot of people suggesting to use OP-AMP for it. can anyone suggest the best way to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the impedance of the source, you can actually do it with only 3 resistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQoXnb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This basically forms a potential divider which is biased to the centre of the power supply rails. When the voltage at the input is at \$-50\mathrm{V}\$, you can work out that you will end up with \$0\mathrm{V}\$ at the output, and when  at \$50\mathrm{V}\$ you will end up with \$5\mathrm{V}\$ at the output.

---

---

To address the comment asking how this works, we have to delve into a bit of circuit theory. Lets first rearrange the above circuit to something we can do some derivations with. This is shown in the top left circuit below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8FekJ.png)</sup>

It is possible to transform a voltage source with a series resistance into a current source with a parallel resistance. In the top right circuit in the diagram above I have made this transformation. Using this transform, we can say that:

$$\begin{matrix}
I_s=\frac{V_s}{R_1} &&& I_{dd}=\frac{V_{dd}}{R_3}=\frac{5}{R_3}
\end{matrix}$$

We can actually then do the transform again. If we group the resistances \$R_1\$ and \$R_3\$ together, and group the current sources together, then do the transform again, we get the bottom right circuit. After the transform, we can say:

$$\begin{matrix}
R_t=\frac{R_1 R_3}{R_1 + R_3} &&& V_i=(I_s + I_{dd})\times R_t
\end{matrix}$$

With a little bit of substitution, we get:

$$V_i = \left(\frac{V_s}{R_1} + \frac{5}{R_3}\right)\times R_t$$

We can see from the circuit that this is now just a simple potential divider with a rather ugly input voltage. So we can say that:

$$V_o = V_i \frac{R_2}{R_2 + R_t} = \left(\frac{V_s}{R_1} + \frac{5}{R_3}\right)\times\frac{R_2 R_t}{R_2 + R_t}$$

We know from the very basics of a potential divider, that there is a linear relationship between the input and output. When the input gets lower, the output does (albeit by a scaled amount). So to start putting a value to the above resistors, we can take some limits. The questions asked for:

$$V_{i_{max}} = 50\mathrm{V} \rightarrow V_{o_{max}} = 5\mathrm{V} $$
$$V_{i_{min}} = -50\mathrm{V} \rightarrow V_{o_{min}} = 0\mathrm{V} $$

So lets work with that. First we will do the minimum limit. What can that tell us about the resistors?

$$\begin{align}
V_o &= \left(\frac{V_s}{R_1} + \frac{5}{R_3}\right)\times\frac{R_2 R_t}{R_2 + R_t}\\\\
0 &= \left(\frac{-50}{R_1} + \frac{5}{R_3}\right)\times\frac{R_2 R_t}{R_2 + R_t}\\\\
\frac{50}{R_1} &= \frac{5}{R_3}\\\\
R_1 &= 10 R_3
\end{align}$$

That's quite handy. It tells us a nice simple relationship between \$R_1\$ and \$R_3\$. It also simplifies the relationship of \$R_t\$ to:

$$\begin{align}
R_t&=\frac{R_1 R_3}{R_1 + R_3}\\\\
R_t&=\frac{10 R_3 R_3}{10 R_3 + R_3}\\\\
R_t&=0.909 R_3
\end{align}$$

Now lets try our maximum case:

$$\begin{align}
V_o &= \left(\frac{V_s}{R_1} + \frac{5}{R_3}\right)\times\frac{R_t R_2}{R_t + R_2}\\\\
5 &= \left(\frac{50}{R_1} + \frac{5}{R_3}\right)\times\frac{R_t R_2}{R_t + R_2}\\\\
5\frac{R_t + R_2}{R_t R_2} &= \frac{50}{R_1} + \frac{5}{R_3}\\\\
5\frac{0.909 R_3 + R_2}{ 0.909 R_3 R_2} &= \frac{50}{10 R_3} + \frac{5}{R_3}\\\\
R_2 &= 1.111 R_3
\end{align}$$

So in this case, we can basically say for the original circuit that:

$$\begin{matrix}
R_1 &= 10 R_3 &&& R_2 &= 1.111 R_3
\end{matrix}$$

From there you can easily pick a value for \$R_3\$ and use it to find the other two resistor values.

Comment: I think the 2nd '-50V' should actually be '50V'. Could you explain exactly how -50V at the input becomes 0 V at the divider output? Are these resistor values specific to the voltage range of -50 to +50?

Comment: @TisteAndii corrected, thanks. In terms of working out the values, I'll add some info in an hour or so when I get a chance.

Comment: @TisteAndii in the mean time, [this](https://gist.github.com/TCWORLD/1bea372adf72a93df1bc) may help - circuit simulation.

Comment: Thanks. It provides an image of whats happening; i can see that both circuits produce the same effect of conditioning the signal but I still dont know *why* or *how* it happens. My knowledge of circuit theory has gaping holes. Would appreciate that edit as soon as you get the chance.

Comment: @TisteAndii I've added the derivation for you. Having done the calculations this time (the original values were an educated guess), the circuit would produce the correct 0-5V output range.

Comment: Thanks. Brilliant explanation. Totally understand now. Though i wonder how your guess was that accurate in the first place; is there something in particular that led you to those values or just your long experience? Also is this circuit good enough for measuring 240 VAC (with the right resistors)? Any isolation needed? And possible pitfalls?

Comment: @TisteAndii +/-50V to +/-2.5 is 20:1. Two 1k's in parallel forming the 2.5V offset is effectively 500R, so 20x500=10k for the input resistor. That was how I made the educated guess. You could use it for measuring the mains, but if you do I would go for much higher resistors (maybe 100k+ for R1) and use extreme care - that may however be too high impedance for the ADC input though, so an op-amp source follower may be required. For mains it may make more sense to use an n:1 isolation transformer to drop the voltage down for the measurement - would certainly be safer.

Comment: Cheat formula there lol...How can very high impedance for the ADC be a bad thing? I assumed the higher the better, to prevent it from loading the source or drawing too much current. Last question, i swear :)

Comment: @TisteAndii the ADC has a S/H capacitor, so the potential divider and the capacitor act as a low pass (RC) filter. As long as the frequencies you want to measure are low enough to not be filtered away, then you can use a higher impedance.

Comment: Hmm, lots of things to consider. So as long as R1*C (the S/H cap) is orders of magnitude smaller than the period of the signal being measured, you're okay. Thanks for taking the time.